# How would you sum $x^k$ from $k=m/2$ to $k=m-1$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, sequences-and-series

How can this be summed: 
$$\sum_{k=\frac{m}2}^{m-1}x^k$$

thank you!

Comment: Factor $x^{m/2}$ out, use geometric sum formula.

Answer (score 4):

Just subtract one geometric series from another:

$$\sum_{k=m/2}^{m-1}x^k=\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}x^k-\sum_{k=0}^{m/2-1}x^k$$

(I’m assuming from your title that you already know how to deal with these sums.)

**Added:** More generally, $$\sum_{k=m}^nx^k=x^m\sum_{k=0}^{n-m}x^k=x^m\left(\frac{x^{n-m+1}-1}{x-1}\right)=\frac{x^{n+1}-x^m}{x-1}=\frac{x^m-x^{n+1}}{1-x}$$ is the general formula for such sums.

Answer (score 2):

This is a partial geometric series.  I am assuming that $m$ is even since you have $m/2$ as a limit.

Using the formula for the sum of a [geometric series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series), we get

$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=m/2}^{m-1}x^k
&=x^{m/2}\sum_{k=0}^{m/2-1}x^k\\
&=x^{m/2}\frac{x^{m/2}-1}{x-1}\\
&=\frac{x^m-x^{m/2}}{x-1}
\end{align}
$$

**Different Methods, Same Result:**

We can compute $\displaystyle\sum_{k=m}^{n-1}ar^k$ in two ways:

1. subtracting two geometric series:
   $$
   \begin{align}
   \sum_{k=m}^{n-1}ar^k
   &=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}ar^k-\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}ar^k\\
   &=a\frac{r^n-1}{r-1}-a\frac{r^m-1}{r-1}\\
   &=a\frac{r^n-r^m}{r-1}\tag{1}
   \end{align}
   $$
2. Pulling out the starting power of $r$:
   $$
   \begin{align}
   \sum_{k=m}^{n-1}ar^k
   &=r^m\sum_{k=0}^{n-m-1}ar^k\\
   &=r^ma\frac{r^{n-m}-1}{r-1}\\
   &=a\frac{r^n-r^m}{r-1}\tag{2}
   \end{align}
   $$

Both $(1)$ and $(2)$ yield the same result.